# Shell script time output over java environment

Tags: java, shell, time

I am running a script from java program using `sshxcute API`.
Script contains:

```
 #!/bin/sh
data=`stat -c%y filename`
echo $data
```

Script running on bash gives output:

```
2014-03-08 13:26:29.335545828 -0800
```

Script running through java program gives output:

```
2014-03-08 21:26:29.335545828 +0000
```

I think the `-0800` is getting added. I need output in first format. How to resolve the issue?

Comment: did you debug your code and see what ssh command is going to be run?

Comment: yes, sshexcute api simply copy the script output to string sysout and returns

Comment: Maybe it's about your and remote server's timezone difference.

Comment: May you show your script?

Comment: May you edit your question and show whole script?

Comment: data=`stat -c%y filename` echo $data

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and worked fine for me. Maybe you have some problems about getting the stat of wrong file.

**ex.sh**

```
filename=$1
data=`stat -c%y $filename`
echo $data
```

When i run  `sh ex.sh x.log` from console, here is what i get:

```
 2014-03-11 16:56:21.000000000 +0200
```

I tried same thing with ganymed ssh api and get the same result.

```
2014-03-11 16:56:21.000000000 +0200
```

Comment: let me try with ganymed ssh api

Comment: I don't think it's about the api you've been using. Two possibilities for me: Timezone difference between your pc and remote pc, or you're doing some mistake about checking the file.

Comment: i have program written using sshexcute ..if possible could you send me your java program to run a script

Comment: i set my java program timezone same to the server timezone

Comment: Sorry, it's not possible. You can write a connection code in minutes.

Comment: No problem, will get back to you after few changes in my progarm. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: For me Ganymed also gives same result,Not able to figure out the issue.Lastly i subtracted 8 hr from the output to get the desired result.